# How to create a table in Entity Framework without Code First from a DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework and this forum... I am using Asp.Net MVC 5 with entity framework v6. I have a DataTable that I would like to import into my existing EF database with its exact structure (same column headers and rows). I cannot do this through a model and code first since the columns in the datatable can be different each time I grab it from disk.

I have searched everywhere and not able to find any help. Here is what I have been playing with:

```
MresTablesDB db = new MresTablesDB();
DataTable betas = resources["betas"] as datable;

//todo: create params with betas
string sql = "CREATE TABLE test ( testid int, col1 varchar(255), col2 varchar(255) )";
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(System.Data.Entity.TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, sql,)??
```

Can this even be done? Thanks!

Comment: You can't create tables dynamically, but you can reverse engineer tables from a database. Perhaps more details on what you are trying to accomplish would offer alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So i have analyst dept at work that enters data into a stand alone app (copy tables from excel) - we consume that data in our code as datatables. How do I put those tables into my EF db - we know the structure of some of the tables but 1/2 we do not know how many columns it might have or what the column names will be.

Comment: Impossible through code first. you'll have to use null database initializer and calculate the SQL queries yourself.